# C# HtmlAgilityPack parse <ul>

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to parse the following HTML.

What I currently have is

```
var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='wrapper']");
```

The html is

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
                <li data="334040566050326217">
                    <span>test1</span>
                </li>
                <li data="334040566050326447">
                    <span>test2</span>
                </li>
    </ul>
```

I need to get the number from the `li data` and the value between the `span` tag. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this might suit your needs.

```
//Assumes your document is loaded into a variable named 'document'

List<string> dataAttribute = new List<string>(); //This will contain the long # in the data attribute
List<string> spanText = new List<string>();      //This will contain the text between the <span> tags
HtmlNodeCollection nodeCollection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='wrapper']//li");

foreach (HtmlNode node in nodeCollection)
{
    dataAttribute.Add(node.GetAttributeValue("data", "null"));
    spanText.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("span").InnerText);
}
```